# Struckt Key Exists in cfqueryparam?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfqueryparam

I have form fields with `checkbox` fields. On my `cfc` page I would like to use `strucktKeyExists` to check if checkbox form fields exist when I run my Insert/Update query. Also I have `null` attribute in my `cfqueryparam` that will set value to true/false if value/field doesn't exist. Here is example of my code:

```
dm_ck0 = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(structKeyExists(FORM, 'frm_ck0'))#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" maxlength="1" null="#yesNoFormat(!len(trim(structKeyExists(FORM, 'frm_ck0'))))#" />
```

So when I submit my form `checkbox` field is `unchecked`. I got an error message back:

```
Invalid data value NO exceeds maxlength setting 1.
```

I'm not sure why this message showed up. Before I set `StrucktKeyExist()` in my `cfqueryparam` my code worked fine. If anyone see where my code is failing please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, set the variable:

```
myVar = structKeyExists(FORM, 'frm_ck0') ? 1 : 0;
```

Use your variable in the query parameter

```
dm_ck0 = <cfqueryparam value="#myVar#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit">
```